# PHP to AngularJS format in view

Tags: php, json, angularjs

If I have a code like this for the view

```
<tr <? if(!$order['Order']['is_active']){ echo "class='inactive_order'";} ?> >
```

can any one please suggest me what would be the angularJS way to write this code for the view?
The JSON version of $order['is_active'] is order.Order.is_active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-class="{'inactive_order': !order.Order.is_active}">
```